# Compose function signature

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, composition, function-composition

I've read that the composition of g :: A -> B and f :: B -> C, pronounced (“f composed of g”), results in another function (arrow) from A -> C. This can be expressed more formally as

> f • g = f(g) = compose :: (B -> C) -> (A -> B) -> (A -> C)

Can the above composition be also defined as below? Please clarify.
In this case the compose function takes the same two functions f and g and return a new function from A -> C.

> f • g = f(g) = compose :: ((B -> C), (A -> B)) -> (A -> C)

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @Erik, functional programming in javascript by Luis Atencio

Comment: Tupling of arguments, as you have done in your last version, is commonly referred to as the "uncurried version" of a function.  Wikipedia has an acceptable article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).  Fun fact: 'curry' is taken from the name of the same Mathematician as 'Haskell', Haskell Curry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First we need to get some things right:

- `f ○ g` means something quite different from `f(g)`.

  - The former is a function that, given an argument `x`, will first feed it to `g`, *then pass on the result to `f`*, and output that final result, i.e. `f(g(x))`.
  - OTOH, `f(g)` means you apply the function `f` to the *value* `g` right away, without waiting for any argument. (`g` just happens to have a function type, but in functional languages, functions can be passed around just like any other values / arguments).

  Unless you're dealing with some pretty wacky polymorphic functions, one of these will be ill-typed. For example, a well-typed composition might be

  ```
  sqrt ○ abs :: Double -> Double
  ```

  whereas a well-typed *application* could be (at least in Haskell)

  ```
  map(sqrt) :: [Double] -> [Double]
  ```

  I'll assume in the following you're talking about `f ○ g`.
- Type signatures must be given for *a function itself*, not for *a function applied to some arguments*. This is something that loads of people get utterly wrong: in `f(x)`, you have a function `f` and an argument `x`. But `f(x)` is *not* a function, only the value that's the result of applying a function to a value! So, you shouldn't write something like `f ○ g :: ...` (unless you're actually talking only about the type that *results* from the composition). Better write just `○ :: ...` (or, in Haskell, `(○) :: ...`).
- Function arrows aren't associative. Most mathematicians likely won't even know what `X -> Y -> Z` is supposed to mean. What it means in languages like Haskell may actually be somewhat surprising:

  ```
  X -> Y -> Z  ≡  X -> (Y -> Z)
  ```

i.e. this is the type of a function that first takes only an argument of type `X`. The result will be again a function, but one that takes only an argument of type `Y`. This function will have, if you like, the `X` value already built-in (in a so-called [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), unless the compiler optimises that away). Giving it also the `Y` value will allow the function to actually do its job and finally yield the `Z` result.

At this point you already have your answer, pretty much: indeed the signatures `X -> Y -> Z` and `(X, Y) -> Z` are essentially equivalent. The process of rewriting this is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

To answer your question in particular: most languages don't normally do any currying, so the signature `((B -> C), (A -> B)) -> (A -> C)` is actually more correct. It corresponds to a function you can call as

```
   compose(f,g)
```

OTOH, the curried signature `(B -> C) -> (A -> B) -> (A -> C)` means that you need to feed in the arguments one by one:

```
   compose(f)(g)
```

Only in languages like Haskell is this the standard style, but you don't need the parens there: all the following are parsed the same in Haskell

```
   compose(f)(g)
   compose f g
   (compose) f g
   (.) f g
   f . g
```

where `.` is in fact the [composition operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:.), which as you can see from the documentation has type

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Comment: The "curried signature `((B -> C) -> (A -> B)) -> (A -> C)`" should actually be `(B -> C) -> ((A -> B) -> (A -> C))`

Comment: Never use copy & paste without letting a compiler typecheck after you...

Answer (score 4):

Since you marked your question with **Javascript** here is an answer from a Javascript point of view.

Assuming I understand your signature properly, you want to adapt the composition function as follows: `(f, g) => x => f(g(x));`. Sure, that works, but you lose flexibility and gain uhm, nothing.

The original curry function is defined in curried form that means, it expects always a single argument. If every function in your whole code expects exactly one argument, then there is no more arity (well, in most cases). It is abstracted away. Currying facilitates function composition, because functions always return a single value. Curried functions are like building blocks. You can put them together in almost any way:

```js
    const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x)),
     comp2 = comp(comp)(comp),
     add = y => x => x + y,
     inc = x => x + 1,
     sqr = x => x * x;
    
    console.log(comp(sqr)(inc)(2)); // 9
    console.log(comp(add)(sqr)(2)(3)); // 7
    console.log(comp2(sqr)(add)(2)(3)); // 25
```

As you can see only in the latter case we must consider the arity.

Currying can only develop its benefits if it is consistently applied for each function of your codebase, because it has a systemic effect.

Comment: nice write-up @LUH3417

Answer (score 3):

First, an open circle is more commonly used: `f ∘ g`.

Second, it would more properly be pronounced "f composed *with* g". ("f composed of g" sounds like `f` is made up of `g`, rather than a new function made up of both.)

Finally, the two types are essentially the same, differing only in how you expect to pass functions to the `compose` function. The first defines the type of a fully curried function, such that `compose` takes one function as an argument, and returns a new function that takes the second function as an argument and returns the composed. This means with `f :: B -> C` and `g :: A -> B`, you can define either (using Haskell syntax)

```
compose :: (B -> C) -> (A -> B) -> (A -> C)
compose f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

or the uncurried version

```
compose' :: ((B -> C), (A -> B)) -> (A -> C)
compose' (f, g) = \x -> f (g x)
```

Either way, the return value is the same; the only difference is in how the arguments are passed. You could write `h = compose f g` or you could write `h = compose' (f, g)`.